# Is there a function in matlab called `taskset()`

Tags: matlab

Is there a function in matlab called `taskset()` - I've searched online but haven't been able to find anything? I'm new to matlab and am wondering if its been deprecated. I found the code [here](http://www.codelooker.com/id/180/1019576.html).

```
function draw_scheduling(P,cnt_t,cnt_p)

P(cnt_p+1,:)=[];
%disp(P);
task=zeros(4,cnt_t);%row =[task number , start , len , process_no ]
for i=1:cnt_t
    [row,col]=find(P==i);
    task(1,i)=i;%task number
    task(2,i)=col(1);%start
    task(3,i)=max(size(row));%len
    task(4,i)=row(1);%process_no
end
fprintf('\n Task NO   -->');for i=1:cnt_t fprintf('%-6d',task(1,i));end
fprintf('\n Start     -->');for i=1:cnt_t fprintf('%-6d',task(2,i));end
fprintf('\n Finish    -->');for i=1:cnt_t fprintf('%-6d',task(2,i)+task(3,i)-1);end
fprintf('\n Processor -->');for i=1:cnt_t fprintf('%-6d',task(4,i));end
fprintf('\n len       -->');for i=1:cnt_t fprintf('%-6d',task(3,i));end


fprintf('\n');

T1=taskset(task(3,:));
start=task(2,:);
processor=task(4,:);

for i=1:cnt_t
    Name_t(i)=cellstr(strcat('T',num2str(i)));
end
T1.Name=Name_t;

add_schedule(T1,'sdsd',start,T1.ProcTime,processor);
get_schedule(T1);
plot(T1);
end
```

Comment: Not that I know of. Perhaps it's a user function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [TORSCHE Scheduling Toolbox](http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox/manual/) by googling for `add_schedule`. It looks like this code uses that toolbox.